# Can I define a generic function with "overridable" return types?

Tags: typescript

I want something like this:

```js
type httpRequestHandler = <Payload>(request: RequestData) => Payload

const httpRouteA: httpRequestHandler = (request) => {
    return 'Test'
}

const httpRouteB: httpRequestHandler = (request) => {
    return 13
}
```

Can the compiler infer `string` and `number` here **WITHOUT** making me do something like `httpRequestHandler<string>` and `httpRequestHandler<number>`?

```js
type PayloadA = ReturnType<typeof httpEndpointA> // string
type PayloadB = ReturnType<typeof httpEndpointB> // number
```

Comment: An example of what you're trying to do that's a bit closer to the actual problem you're trying to solve would be enormously beneficial here.  See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thanks for the advice @RobertHarvey. The actual problem I'm trying to solve is I want to get the return type of my backend function routes directly from the Typescript compiler instead of having to annotate everything. Then I can import them in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working like this:

```js
const httpRouteA = (request: RequestData) => {
    return 'Test'
}

type PayloadA = ReturnType<typeof httpEndpointA> // string.

const httpRouteB = (request: RequestData) => {
    return 13
}

type PayloadB = ReturnType<typeof httpEndpointB> // number.
```

It's a tradeoff since I have to type the function parameters everytime, but the compiler correctly infers the return type here.